# Simple reservation system for a card game

Tags: front-end

I would like to set up a wordpress site for scheduling a four-player card game.
Assume each post is created to announce a card game with a date/time/location provided.
Assume each user is a registered subscriber.

I would like a simple way to click on a seat a the table and have that click reserve that person's spot in the game.  Ideally, anyone that looks at the post could see what seats are empty and which are taken.  For the spots that are taken, I would like to see the username of the person that reserved the seat.

Finally, giving up a seat should be as simple as clicking on your username and the seat would go from reserved to empty.  Also, clicking on a seat with someone else's username on it would do nothing.

Any pointers on where to start?  I have users and registration set up using the "simple membership" plugin.  So, now what I really need is the frontend-editable chair.  I am pretty lost on how to implement this feature.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to do some custom coding, or hire a programmer to do it for you